# How do I write a JavaScript function that extracts a number of characters from a string (from the beginning of the string)?

Tags: javascript, html

The input data must be retrieved from a text field and the result will be displayed in a div container when a button or link is pressed.

Comment: [String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can do it using [.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method on a string.

Like this:

```js
const str = document.getElementById("str");
const num = document.getElementById("num");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  result.innerHTML = str.value.substr(0, Number(num.value));
});
```

```css
.mb { display: block; margin-bottom: 20px;} /* Just for styling */
```

```html
<strong>Enter the string:</strong>
<input type="text" id="str" class="mb" />

<strong>No of characters:</strong>
<input type="number" id="num" class="mb" />

<h1 id="result" class="mb"></h1>
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```